# RequireJS production / dev variables

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

I need to inject a angularjs module dependency when the app is in production mode.  I'm using requirejs to handle script loading.

Currently, I've got some if blocks setup in my asp.net file to set a global variable like:

```
@if (!HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled){
    <script type="text/javascript">window.env = "production";</script>
}
```

and then in my javascript i do:

```
if(window.env === "production"){
    app.requires.push('templates-main');
}
```

is there a preferred way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may, at least, to achive it via RequireJs optimizer:

You may add this to your build config:

```
 pragmas: {
    production: true
 },
```

---

```
//>>includeStart("production", pragmas.production);
app.requires.push('templates-main')
//>>includeEnd("production");
```

More about requirejs pragmas [here](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js#L243).